# I'm getting a Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed using core and Identity Server

Tags: angular, openid, identityserver4, angular-oauth2-oidc

I have an Angular app using .net core and Identity Server 4 for authentication. I'm using this angular service for openid https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc

After I log in I'm redirected back to my web app with a token, but I keep getting this in my output log? How can I correct this issue or where can I look?

```
Information: Identity.Application was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
```

Comment: Identity.Application refers to a scheme. You may have to set DefaultScheme (or one of the others) to the scheme you are using.